# The goal of solving a Heat/Wave Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, wave-equation

This is an example of a heat equation:

$u_t=u_{xx}$, where $0<x<1$, $t>0$

$u_x(0,t)=u_x(1,t)=0$ and $u(0,t)=g(t)$ .

> The heat equation is a parabolic partial differential equation that describes the distribution of heat (or variation in temperature) in a given region over time.

I've found that $u$ is temperature as a function of space and time
$u_t$ is the rate of change of temperature at a point over time and $u_{xx}$is the second spatial derivative(thermal conductions) of temperature in the  x direction.

However, I can't imagine what we are doing, what changes when the region we deal with changes etc. That is the question.

(More generally: what is the idea behind solving a heat/wave equation? What do we want to do and how are we doing it? )

Comment: Its not really clear what you mean by "What do we what to do..." could you clarify your intent?

Comment: Very broad. We usually start by using an ansatz such as $f(x,y,z,t) = X(x)Y(y)Z(z)T(t)$ and then separate variables. Fourier series or other types of transforms often figure also to incorporate boundary conditions. The best way to get a sense of these is to look up specific equations and work through solutions. They are in many standard undergraduate texts, not to mention websites you can find with searching.

Answer (score 0):

Let $u(x,t)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty C(n,t)\cos n\pi x$ so that it automatically satisfies $u_x(0,t)=u_x(1,t)=0$ ,

Then $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty C_t(n,t)\cos n\pi x=-\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty n^2\pi^2C(n,t)\cos n\pi x$

$\therefore C_t(n,t)=-n^2\pi^2C(n,t)$

$\dfrac{C_t(n,t)}{C(n,t)}=-n^2\pi^2$

$\int\dfrac{C_t(n,t)}{C(n,t)}dt=-\int n^2\pi^2~dt$

$\ln C(n,t)=-n^2\pi^2t+a(n)$

$C(n,t)=A(n)e^{-n^2\pi^2t}$

$\therefore u(x,t)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty A(n)e^{-n^2\pi^2t}\cos n\pi x$

$u(0,t)=g(t)$ :

$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty A(n)e^{-n^2\pi^2t}=g(t)$

$\therefore u(x,t)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty A(n)e^{-n^2\pi^2t}\cos n\pi x$ , where $A(n)$ is the solution of $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty A(n)e^{-n^2\pi^2t}=g(t)$